# Join columns to search string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these tables which I would like to query:

```
create table employees
(
    id bigint generated by default as identity (maxvalue 2147483647),
    username varchar(100) not null,
    password varchar(60) not null,
    account_id bigint,
    role_id bigint,
    first_name varchar(150),
    last_name varchar(150),
    primary key (id)
);

create table accounts
(
    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    account_name varchar(150) not null,
    account_group_id bigint not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

Test data:

```
insert into employees (id, username, password, account_id) values
     (1, "test user", "pass", 3),
     (2, "test user2 ", "pass", 4);

insert into accounts (id, account_name, account_group_id) values
     (1, "main", 3),
     (2, "second", 4);
     (3, "third", 4);
```

I need to create a query which searches into table `employees` by `account_name`. I tried this:

Example when I send search param `second` I need to get a row result: `test user2`

```
SELECT * FROM common.employees e
WHERE e.??????? iLIKE CONCAT('%', :params, '%')
```

Do you know how I can join the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly parameterize Sql identifier(columns, tables), You can only parameterize values.

> Prepared statements can take parameters: values that are substituted into the statement when it is executed.
> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html

In your code. `WHERE e.???????` cannot be easily parameterized. You need to use plpgsql functions.

```
prepare test(text,int) as SELECT e.* FROM  employees e
join accounts a on e.account_id = a.id
 WHERE a.account_name iLIKE CONCAT('%', $1, '%')
 and a.account_group_id  =  $2;
```

If your already have `test` prepare statement in the active session then `DEALLOCATE test;`

suppose the account_group_id = 1 then:
`execute  test('third', 1);`

Comment: I need also to include columns `account_group_id` and `account_id` into the result. Can you update the query please?

Comment: @user1285928 updated. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Join the 2 tables like that ([result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5BYpoAKxnMauYzrnWnyJJD/0))

```
SELECT e.* FROM 
employees e, accounts a
WHERE 
e.account_id = a.id
and a.account_name = 'second'
```

Comment: I need also to include columns `account_group_id` and `account_id` into the result.

Comment: Just replace `select e.*` by `select *`

Answer (score 1):

To include columns `account_group_id` and `account_id` into the result you can get as below :
Though `e.*`  will contain all the info that is present in employee table which include account_id as well. So if you want to customized your result set you can do that according to your need:

```
SELECT e.*,a.account_group_id 
FROM  employees e
INNER JOIN accounts a ON a.id = e.account_id
WHERE a.account_name = param
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just use an inner join and join on the account table using the `account_id` and add a `WHERE` clause where you only select from `employee` where the `account_name` equals your `param`....which I'm guessing will be a `varchar`

```
SELECT e.*, a.account_group_id 
FROM  employees e
INNER JOIN accounts a ON a.id = e.account_id
WHERE a.account_name = param
```

or

```
WHERE a.account_name LIKE '%param%'
```

but the second may bring back other users as the param could exist in other names.

Also I don't believe the data in your example is correct as surely the `account_id` would link to the `id` in the accounts table...so passing `second` would in fact get you an employee who's `account_id` is 2.

Comment: I need also to include columns `account_group_id` and `account_id` into the result. Can you update the query please?

Comment: @user1285928 Just add it to the `SELECT`. I've updated the query for you